# Flutter version solving failed with cloud_firestore and firebase_core

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Running `pub get` or `pub upgrade` results in the following error:

```
Running "flutter pub upgrade" in <project-name>...      

Because cloud_firestore >=0.13.3 <0.14.0-dev.1 depends on firebase_core ^0.4.4 and cloud_firestore >=0.11.0 <0.13.3 depends on firebase_core ^0.4.0, cloud_firestore >=0.11.0 <0.14.0-dev.1 requires firebase_core ^0.4.0.
So, because <project-name> depends on both cloud_firestore ^0.13.0+1 and firebase_core ^0.5.0+1, version solving failed.
pub upgrade failed (1; So, because <project-name> depends on both cloud_firestore ^0.13.0+1 and firebase_core ^0.5.0+1, version solving failed.)
```

My `pubspec.yaml`:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  google_sign_in: "^4.5.1"
  firebase_core: "^0.5.0+1"
  firebase_auth: "^0.18.1+2"
```

Project is created by following official guides in the last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incrementing the cloud_firestory version in `pubspec.yml` solved this:

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+1
```